# Deleting the row in database is not working.How to get the ID of the row i clicked?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Each row have a id and phone number.  I know the position and id are differing. but i got the id of the position through getitemID. and still not working.
How to get the ID of the row i clicked?

```
              public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
   // DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */


    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Reading all contacts

    contacts = db.getAllContacts();

    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        log = "ID"+cn.getID()+"Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();


        // Writing Contacts to log
        planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(log) );
    }

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
    registerForContextMenu(mainListView);
}

            public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
       {  
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        try
        {

        //  info.position will give the index of selected item

                        if(item.getTitle()=="DELETE")
                        { 
                            Contact cn= new Contact();

                            //cn._id=info.position+1; 

                        cn._id= Math.abs((int)listAdapter.getItemId(info.position));
                             db.deleteContact(new Contact(cn._id,cn._phone_number));
                            listAdapter.remove(listAdapter.getItem(info.position));

                            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }  
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }  

                        return true;  
           }  
        catch(Exception e)
        {
                return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Database code

```
             import android.content.ContentValues;
         import android.content.Context;
         import android.database.Cursor;
         import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
         import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

         import java.util.ArrayList;
         import java.util.List;

         class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
public final String KEY_ID = "id";

public  final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String DELETE_ID= "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS +" WHERE"+" "+ KEY_ID +"="+contact._id;
    db.execSQL(DELETE_ID);

}


// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));

            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(1));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

}

Comment: For instance, this `if(item.getTitle()=="DELETE")` doesn't work. Use `equals()` for comparing strings. `info.position will give the index of selected item` yes. But it won't give you the **table id**. The ListView position is something different from the id in the table.

Comment: Are you creating the rows programmatically? or they are static? if it is a programmatically method are you using some adapter?

Comment: creating through insert query. delete worked. list got deleted. but the database didnt get . and i know info.position and id are not same. so i used the getitemID.

Comment: Can you post the adapter code?

Comment: I updated. kindly check

Answer (score 0):

Your delete query is incorrect.

You should have a space after "WHERE"

```
String DELETE_ID= "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS +"    WHERE"+""+KEY_ID+"="+contact._id;
```

Has you can see there is no space after the "WHERE" reserved word

**EDIT**

KEY_ID shouldn't be an id. It should be the name of the column where you're saving the id. However yo didn't provide us with such information so we can't say what column it should be.

Also check your ids and see if they really match the ones you got on your adapter. Let us know your **insert** query so we can better help you.

**EDIT2**

You have a really messy code let me tell you. I suggest you clear it before going any further. However you can try this to retrieve the real id of the contact when you're calling the delete method:

```
String s = listAdapter.getItem(info.position);
int id = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.indexOf("D")+1,s.indexOf("P")));
db.deleteContact(new Contact(id,cn._phone_number));
```

Comment: +" WHERE"+"   "+ KEY_ID+"="+contact._id; this is the code. didnt copy paste properly. still didnt work

Comment: That's not what you have on your answer.

Comment: Also KEY_ID shouldn't be an Id but the column name instead.

Comment: actually in code there is space. but here when i copy paste that space is not getting added properly. so it is not the problem in query

Comment: public final String KEY_ID = "id";

Comment: Why index of (D) and P are used?

Comment: To get the "id" that is between "ID" and "PHONE". So, between "D" and "P". Since this is the way you're transforming the contacts into text.

Comment: I will explain it to you nice and easy. "Get me the string between D and P and transform it into an integer.". The string between D and P is actually the id of your contact. :)

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't forget to mark it as solution to easily help others that may have the same problem as you. Have a nice day.

Comment: But this code wont work if i display only the phone number in list rite?            log ="Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();

Comment: No. If you want to do that you will have to use a custom adapter and not a String adapter. From what I've seen from your coding you seem to be learning and that should be a more advanced topic.

Comment: You should read a topic on "custom base adapters". The question has been answer and there is a lot of work you still need to do before getting into that. If you don't want to display the id take him out. However you will have to remove the contact from your database using the phone_number and not the id. I will not keep this discussion since you need to study a bit more this basic stuff. I wish you good luck.